# command to check status of message queue and shared memory in linux?

Tags: linux, ipc, message-queue, shared-memory

Sorry to ask such a silly question as i am  noob in  unix. 
what are the  unix commands to find shared memory and message queue and how to kill them ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`ipcs(1)` provides information on the IPC facilities and `ipcrm(1)` can be used to remove the IPC objects from the system.

List shared memory segments:

```
ipcs -m
```

List message queues:

```
ipcs -q
```

Remove shared memory segment created with `shmkey`:

```
ipcrm -M key
```

Remove shared memory segment identified by `shmid`:

```
ipcrm -m id
```

Remove message queue created with `msgkey`:

```
ipcrm -Q key
```

Remove message queue identified by `msgid`:

```
ipcrm -q id
```