# how to detect read from deleted mmap file?

Tags: c, posix, shared-memory

I have process1 create shared memory by the following steps in RedHat 6.5 :

```
if((shm_fd1 = shm_open(sharedfile1, (O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_RDWR),
                   (S_IREAD | S_IWRITE))) > 0 ) {
    printf("shared memory shm_fd1 created !! \n") ;
}
ftruncate(shm_fd1, sizeof(struct_order)*iGlbCallCnt );
if((ptrsharedCall = (struct_order*) mmap(0, sizeof(struct_order)*iGlbCallCnt , (PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE),
               MAP_SHARED, shm_fd1, 0)) == MAP_FAILED) 
{
    printf("shared memory shm_fd1 mmap error , errno=(%d)\n",errno) ;
    printf("try to remove /dev/shm/ file \n") ;
    exit(0) ;
}
```

The procees2  read  data from what process1 create  :

```
if((shm_fd1 = shm_open(sharedfile1, (O_RDWR),
                   (S_IREAD | S_IWRITE))) < 0 ) {
    printf("shared memory shm_fd1  error  !! \n") ;
    exit(0) ;
}
ftruncate(shm_fd1, sizeof(struct_order)*iGlbCallCnt );
if((ptrsharedCall = (struct_order*) mmap(0, sizeof(struct_order)*iGlbCallCnt , (PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE),
               MAP_SHARED, shm_fd1, 0)) == MAP_FAILED)
{
    printf("shared memory shm_fd1 mmap error , errno=(%d)\n",errno) ;
    printf("try to remove /dev/shm/ file \n") ;
    exit(0) ;
}
```

It works fine ,  but I like to inform process2 while process1 delete the shared memory file  by :

```
sprintf(filenm1,"%s%s","/dev/shm/",sharedfile1) ;
unlink(filenm1);
```

So far I have no idea how process2 to detect that shared memory file is already deleted ,any idea ?

Edit :

Is it ok to use stat in shared memory file ?  process2 can detect file deleted by :

```
    #include <sys/stat.h>

    if(stat(filenm1,&sts) < 0)
    {
        printf("(%s) deleted \n",filenm1) ;
        exit(0)  ;
    }
```

Comment: make both process communicate? btw take a look at [how to check status of shared memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786466/command-to-check-status-of-message-queue-and-shared-memory-in-linux)

Comment: @UmNyobe , yes , that is a good idea !! since it is IPC , process1 can inform process2 for that !! thanks !!

Comment: on second thought , if process1 core dump, then process2 won't know, still keep reading shared memory , so it is not so perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to get a notification in one process when another one exits or otherwise decides it's done communicating.  Rather than trying to communicate this bit of state via the same shared memory IPC, you can do it easily by making a good old TCP connection between the two processes.  Then when one stops or closes the connection, the other will be notified, and this notification is guaranteed by the operating system (though it may take a bit of time to arrive).